# Card Number field missing for BMO Group

Tags: yodlee

We use Yodlee API to get the bank code 2483 BMO Financial Group (Canada) Bank.
The issue is that we are missing the card number field for authentication. 
We have this issue only with BMO Group.
Can you please check this issue at the earliest and let us know what needs to be done. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the card number field for authentication for BMO using Yodlee's SDK.
Below is the list of fields which Yodlee's SDK returns for bank code 2483
1)Enter BMO Debit Card(this is the field where you need to enter the debit card number)
2)Enter BMO Credit Card(16 digit) (this is the field where you need to enter the credit card details)
3)Password

You can pass either of the 1st two fields to Yodlee.

Please try once using the Yodlee's sampleApp and if you are still seeing the issue, please raise a service request using Yodlee customer care(YCC) tool. And please mention your cobrandID, SOAP URL which you are using and we will look into it.

Comment: Hi, I am still facing the same issue. I am not getting the card number field for BMO. Cobrand ID: 24610005220 and soap URL is https://upgrade.smarteronlinebanking.com/yodsoap/services. I have already raised a service request in Yodlee money center and I was redirected to this forum. If I have to raise a service request in another place, can you please give me the URL. Thanks